# Calling jquery function using onclick from td of table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to call a jQuery function upon clicking on the 4th 'td' as below.
But it is not calling the function, I have tried different ways to get the row from the table.

```
<table class='logtable'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Log Note</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?foreach ( $logRows as $logRow ){?>
            <tr class="logtr">
                <td><?=readable_date($logRow['date_created'])?></td>
                <td><?=$logRow['first_name']></td>
                <td><?=$logRow['log_note']?></td>
                <td class="js-delete-log"  data-log-id=<?=$logRow['log_id']?>><span class="delete"> <i class="fa fa-times"></i></span></td>

            </tr>
            <?}?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Below is the JQuery function which is called from the 'td'.

```
// jQuery function to delete the log

$( "body" ).on( "click", ".js-delete-log", function(event) {
        var el = $(this);
        var log_id = el.data('log-id');

              $.post( "../ajax/delete_logs.php", {log_id:log_id,action:'delete_log'} )                         
              location.reload();
    });

});
```

Can anyone please help on what's the issue here?

I tried the below method also.

```
//   $("table.logtable tr.logtr td.js-delete-log").click(function() {
```

Comment: any error in console

Comment: have you checked your code "<td><?=$logRow['first_name']></td>" you have missed the "?>"

Comment: just do a simple form if you are reloading the page no need for ajax

Comment: can you please check using alert that you have data-log-id in valid form that you want or not?

Comment: It seems that there is  extra identation }); .

Answer (score 1):

i think the problem come from this

```
 <td class="js-delete-log"  data-log-id=<?=$logRow['log_id']?>>
```

Try this one

```
<td class="js-delete-log"  data-log-id=<?php echo $logRow['log_id'] ?>>
```

Comment: That's correct, but we can't say he is wrong here until we know his version.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `attr()` , reload the page when ajax is successful:

```
var log_id = el.attr('data-log-id');
$.post( "../ajax/delete_logs.php", {log_id:log_id,action:'delete_log'},function(data){
location.reload();
});
```

Comment: why to use attr if jquery provide .data()

Answer (score 0):

your code working fine you have extra "});"  tag in your code may cause of problem

```js
$( "body" ).on( "click", ".js-delete-log", function(event) {
        var el = $(this);
        var log_id = el.data('log-id');
        alert(log_id)

//              $.post( "../ajax/delete_logs.php", {log_id:log_id,action:'delete_log'} )                         
  //            location.reload();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class='logtable'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Log Note</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            
            <tr class="logtr">
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td class="js-delete-log" data-log-id='50' >  4</td>

            </tr>
          
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? (just to ensure that it reaches this event handler so that we can confirm if the error is in event binding or later)

```
$( document.body ).on( "click", ".js-delete-log", function(event) {
        alert("clicked");
});
```

Comment: @Wings2fly if this is not working then the issue in rendering of td as A-Kohar has pointed out. Check your browser's dev-tools to ensure that your td looks like how you want it to be. Hopefully this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `});` here

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", ".js-delete-log", function(event) {
    var el = $(this);
    var log_id = el.data('log-id');

          $.post( "../ajax/delete_logs.php", {log_id:log_id,action:'delete_log'} ); //You missed the semicolon here but it's not creating the issue                        
          location.reload();
    //}); Remove this line

});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a extra `});` in your code, this should work

```
$(function(){
    $( "body" ).on( "click", ".js-delete-log", function(event) {
       // your code here....
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$(document).on( "click", ".js-delete-log .delete", function(e) {
    var el = $(this);
    var log_id = el.parent().data('log-id');
    alert(log_id);             
});
```